# Selection in my console menu doesnt work, c++

Tags: c++, console

Im net to coding and I have a problem with my menu.
It doesnt work when I press 1 nothing works.
i dont know what is wrong with my code.

Here is my code https://ghostbin.co/paste/57oz5

```
int select()
{

    int selection;
    do
    {
        selection = menu();
        switch (selection)
        {
        case 1:    DLL();
            break;
        case 2:    Beta();
            break;  cout << "Exiting program.\n\n\n";
        }
    } while (selection != 2);
    return 0;
}

int menu()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "         -------------\n";
    cout << "         |Loader menu|\n";
    cout << "         -------------\n";
    cout << "      1) Finished Version\n";
    cout << "                     " << endl;
    cout << "      2) Beta Version \n";

    Time();

    cin >> choice;
    while (choice < 1 || choice > 2)
    {
        cout << "Invalid Selection. Enter 1, or 2: ";
        cin >> choice;
    }
    return choice;
}

int DLL()
{

    cout << "test" << endl;


    return 0;
}

int Beta()
{

    cout << "test" << endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
```

I hope someone can help me and tell what the problem is.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as images. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: i included the code from the link, but it is incomplete. Please include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: @æryx Define "doesnt work" exactly. What DOES it do when you press 1? Also, the `cout` in `select()` is in the wrong place, and the loop doesn't exit until the user enters 2. What does `main()` look like? We can't see it.